# PC Pro Tools exporting regions

Tags: exporting, regions

Dont know if this is a stupid question but, my band mate has been putting down some guitar tracks, in most cases dual guitar parts, on Pro Tools (Version 10 0r 11 as he tells me.)and wants to export them separately.Now, He says that the only way he can do this on his PC is to wait for the track to play through in real time every time he wants to export a region therefore making this long and laborious. Is there something he's missing? I don't seem to have this problem on my Mac.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function "Consolidate Selection," and it will create new files in your Audio folder with whatever was selected at the time (file name will default to a derivative of the track name). Any fades/crossfades will be rendered into the new files; so make sure you want them there. Selections that span multiple tracks will create a new file for each track. This is faster than real-time.